# Getting a Value if a Field and Record number is known?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good Evening,

I am working on a Combo Search Form that is designed to search for information by criteria. The form has a combo box containing field values and a text box beside it. The selection of a field value in the combo box will fill in the text box beside it with the relevant information for that record, all the relevant information is contained in the PetTable.

I have managed to get the combo box to display the fields from the PetTable by setting the rowSource to PetTable and the sourceType to Field List... however that's where I hit my dead end.

In the Text Box beside the combo-box I tried grabbing the value of the combo box and putting it into the textbox by making the Text box control source "=ComboBox", however this just created a textbox which has a literal text string to that of the combo box.

My next thought was to make the text box Control source "=PetTable.PetComboBox" my thought was that the PetTable references the table with my information and the "PetComboBox" becomes the field a need to get. This did not work either and gave a #Name error"

What should be happening is: In the Combo-box if I selected [Pet Name], I would hope that the textbox beside it becomes "Fido" but instead it also becomes [Pet Name].

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Thanks

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX63E.png)

Comment: RowSourceType should probably be Table/Query, not FieldList.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change the Row Source Type of the Combo Box to "Table/Query". Then in the "Row Source" click on the "..." to open up the Query Builder. Select the table that you want. Add the columns that you want. I would suggest the table's primary key PetID, and then any other fields - in your case at least PetName. You may also want to sort by PetName to make it easier for the user to scroll through. Close the Query Builder and save the changes. Change the combo box's ColumnCount to 2, and set the Column Widths to be "0cm;6cm" (setting the first column to have a width of 0 means that it is not displayed to the user).

Now move to you TextBox, and set the Control Source to be:

```
=[Combo0].Column(1)
```

Note that columns in a combox box are 0-indexed, so the first column is column 0, the second (in your case containing PetName) is column 1.

As you actually want to show the field names, rather than the data in the combo box, then you will need to set the RowSourceType to be "Field List", and then select the table name as the RowSource.

You will then need a small piece of VBA to lookup the value of that field in the table for the current record:

```
Sub sListFieldData()
    If Not IsNull(Me!Combo0) Then
        Me!Text2 = DLookup(Me!Combo0, "tblPet", "PetID=" & Me!PetID)
    Else
        Me!Text2 = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

And you will then need to call this procedure in the combo box's AfterUpdate event (to catch when it has been changed by the user) and also in the form's Current event (to catch when the user moves between records):

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    Call sListFieldData
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Call sListFieldData
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi Applecore, Thank you for your response, unfortunately this did not have the desired effect. The (interesting) requirements specify that the combo-box be comprised of fields, and based on the currently viewed record, come up with the value of that field and record number. I will add an image of the desired effect above as admittedly I probably just suck at explaining.

Comment: I think that I see what you are after. So you have a table called Pets, with Fields PetID, PetName, PetDescription, etc. You want the combo box to display the NAMES of these fields rather than VALUES, and then when one of these fields is selected, populate a text box with the value of that field for the current record?

Comment: Yes, This is correct! Thank you for your continued help